# how to transfer or transform html <li> to html <datalist>

Tags: html, node.js, express

I have some object in li in my html file I want to transfer same items to html datalist in same html file I am working in node js express framework application where data in li comes from sql databse

I have tried coating li inside datalist but it did not work

```
<input type="text" id="txtAutoComplete" list="names"/><!--your input textbox-->
        <datalist id="names">
            <option>
            <% shipper_names.forEach((shipper_names, index)=>{%>
                <ul id="names">
                    <li>
                           <%= shipper_names.Shipper_Name%>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            <%})%>
            </option>
        </datalist>
```

expected result is an autocomplete text box but when I tried to put variable between option tag of datalist it did not work than i tried to put li inside  tag of datalist  its also not working but when I removed datalist  list tag from html file list is displaying perfectly

Comment: Why not just add them as `<option>` elements within the `datalist`? That's how the [`datalist` element is supposed to work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist).

Comment: Tried but not working

Comment: @rushirajsinhrana not working why?

Comment: Please show the code where you are trying that, because that's the only one that has a hope of working.

Comment: also, what is the point in having a `<ul>` containing only one `<li>`?

Comment: when i tried  <% shipper_names.forEach((shipper_names, index)=>{%>
                    <ul id="names">
                        <li>
                               <%= shipper_names.Shipper_Name%>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                <%})%> list of data is was sawing perfectly

Comment: but when i tried         <input type="text" id="txtAutoComplete" list="names"/><!--your input textbox-->
            <% shipper_names.forEach((shipper_names, index)=>{%>
   <datalist id="names">
                <option>                
                    <%= shipper_names.Shipper_Name%></option>
    <%})%>
            </datalist> its not sawing any thing

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio sir <li><%= shipper_names.Shipper_Name%> <li> where content between li tags is variable and data comes from js file

Comment: `datalist` should be printed outside the loop: `<datalist> <% ... %> [<option> TAGS] <% ... %>  </datalist>`

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio thanks for your help sir your answer is working perfectly for me my new codes are as below and getting exact result what is want    <div>
                <input type="text" id="txtAutoComplete" list="names"/><!--your input textbox-->
            <datalist id="names">
                    <% shipper_names.forEach((shipper_names, index)=>{%>
                <option id=<%= shipper_names.Shipper_ID%>>
                    <%= shipper_names.Shipper_Name%></option>
                <%})%>
            </datalist>
            </div>

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div>
            <input type="text" id="txtAutoComplete" list="names" />
            <!--your input textbox-->
            <datalist id="names">
                <% shipper_names.forEach((shipper_names, index)=>{%>
                <option id=<%= shipper_names.Shipper_ID%>>
                    <%= shipper_names.Shipper_Name%></option>
                <%})%>
            </datalist>
</div>
```

this is working correctly